# Chome Extension - QuotaExceededError localStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm developing a Chrome extension and using old localStorage to store settings and cache instead of new `chrome.storage.local` and `chrome.storage.sync`. I have `unlimitedStorage` permission and then my cache becomes huge. I'm receiving `QuotaExceededError`.

How to overcome the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is not, and will not be, unlimited

The fact that the [`unlimitedStorage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#unlimitedStorage) permission does not apply to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is stated in the documentation. The referenced bug, [issue 58985](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58985), was marked as "WontFix" in December of 2010. Thus, there is not, and will not be, a solution for you to store unlimited data in `localStorage`. You will need to select some other method of storing your data.

### Unlimited storage options

#### [`storage.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-local)

Your options include [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) which is explicitly intended for extensions to store data. You can store data that is local to the machine, using [`storage.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-local) (can be unlimited with the `unlimitedStorage` permission), or data that is synchronized across the user's Google account, with [`storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync) (quota is *not* set to unlimited by `unlimitedStorage`).

#### [Web SQL Database](https://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/)

There are other options for storing data. For instance, the [Web SQL Database](https://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/), which is specifically granted unlimited storage by the `unlimitedStorage` permission.

#### HTML5 local [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/) <sup><sub><sup>([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File))</sup></sub></sup>

The amount of data you can store with the File API becomes unlimited with the `unlimitedStorage` permission. You can also separately request a specific quota size with a call to [`webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota()`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/11/Quota-Management-API-Fast-Facts), without using the `unlimitedStorage` permission. When you do, the user will be asked to approve the storage request. If you do use the `unlimitedStorage` permission, you do not need to separately request a quota.

#### What to use

What is best to use will depend on exactly what you are using storage for. You have provided no information as to your actual use, so there is no way for us to gauge what might be a good fit in your case.

### Application cache

As to your issue with the application cache growing to a large size with the `unlimitedStorage` permission: Yes, the documenation explicitly states that declaring the `unlimitedStorage` permission will result in the application cache becoming unlimited. If this is an issue, you will need to not declare the `unlimitedStorage` permission.